# HttpResponse & string android

Tags: android, performance

I wrote a code..There I want to validate something.In my code contain "HttpResponse response;" variable.I want to write,

```
if(response>="0"){
 //do somthing
}
```

but can't above thing. bcs response is not string...How to do that?

Comment: `if (response != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityUtils is static helpers for dealing with entities.

http://www.developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html‎

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response);
if(result >="0"){
 //do somthing
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to explain why this might work?

Answer (score 1):

```
response.toString()
```

try that, you should also look at writing your questions more formally.